# will a part time job to make extra money effect my MBA application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I graduated from undergrad 5.5 years ago and have been working full time ever since. I worked in the hospitality industry in operation management for catering and hotels. I have now decided to take a break from my career path and pursue an MBA, wanting to shift my career to the next level. I left my job in May, moved back home an have been studying for the GMAT exam and work as a part time bartender at a steakhouse. In my top school application, they ask my current job. Do I put that I am a bartender? will this effect my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't, but who knows. If your employer is a corporation, you could probably list them as your employer and that you are part time while you study. Say that the company is a steakhouse. I doubt that they expect more than that.

But, it is a good thing that you want to concentrate on studying up in preparation for the MBA, so stress that more than the specific job description.

Some would just ignore it. Some would get a chuckle. Others ..., well, there are lots of sorts of people in the world.

Just make your application show the strength of your background and the likelihood of future success. That is what they will be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the country on one mayor point. ***Scholarships.*** For various countries, scholarships (at least government ones) are only available to full time studies (and traditional super long programs like 4 years masters or doctorates), meaning it would be very difficult to keep a job, even a part time one. However, if you werent planning to apply to one of those programs and a scholarship for them, then there shouldn't be much problem.